# Symfony DOM Crawler shows that the current node list is empty

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

Here is part of my code:

```
$heading_text = '';
$heading_nodes = $crawler->filter($heading_selector);
if(count($heading_nodes->siblings()) > 0) {
   $heading_text = str_replace('Something', 'Else', htmlentities($heading_nodes->eq(0)->text()));
}
```

I **know** that some of the pages I am crawling will not have any element with the `$heading_selector`. However, that's why I was relying on `siblings()` to calculate the number of headings and proceed if the value was more than 0.

However, I still got the same error `Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.`. The error was caused by `$heading_nodes->siblings()`.

So, if I cannot use `count` with `siblings()` to check if a DOM element exists without throwing an error, what else can I do?

I am using the Symfony DOM crawler: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html.

Thanks.

Comment: Having siblings doesn't mean these siblings also satisfy your selector. You're still trying to `->eq(0)` on something that is empty. (As a note, I don't know about this DOM crawler lib so I'm pretty much guessing, but this seems like a pretty straightforward/common API.) You probably just want to test `if ($heading_nodes->count() > 0)`.

Comment: Thanks @Jeto. :) I don't fully understand this part "Having siblings doesn't mean these siblings also satisfy your selector.". Could you please give me an example?

Comment: A sibling is just an element that is at the same level. So a heading element could be at the same level as a div, or a paragraph, etc., or even a different heading (that wasn't matched by your initial filter).

Comment: Thanks @Jeto. :) The `count()` method is not mentioned in the documentation of the library. So, I don't know if it would work.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php#L1080 ? (since `filter` seems to return a `Crawler` instance).

Comment: Haha. Thanks @jeto. :) I should have also looked at the source code.